# Retrieving hidden cells from excel file in PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

How to retrieve hidden cells in a .xslx (excel) file, using PHPExcel ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read How to Ask.

Comment: @Anantha Raju C, Thanks for your interest! I think question is simple to understand for those who ever worked with PHPExcel, that's why needs no code

Comment: i don't think there is any ambiguity in question, but mean people down vote just for ego.

Comment: It is not about if question is clear or not. It's about that you don't want to show what have you tried so far. That's why are downvotes.

Comment: you may be right $ S.I

Comment: then this was problem specific to me, why should some-one downvote question ? it means this isn't a valid question, if someone else have same question or interested to answer he will definetly ignore it. World is full of fools,

Comment: What you mean by `hidden cell` do you mean hidden row or column?

Comment: it was hidden column,

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve the values of cells in hidden rows or columns in exactly the same way you retrieve values of cells in non-hidden rows or columns.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('C1')
    ->getValue();
```

will work whether the cell is hidden or not.

"Hiding" cells, is something that the MS Excel GUI does, but the cell is still just a normal cell to PHPExcel.